# How do i mock a list of Key,Value pairs (in angular) which does not have indices?

Tags: javascript, java, angular, spring-boot, jasmine

I am unit testing an **angular** application using **Jasmine** and i am in it.
The application has a back-end written in **Spring boot**, which exposes some API's.

The content received from one of the API's (GET request) is a **List of Mapped Key,Value(Object,Value) pairs**.

What i want is to mock the response such that it looks the same as below (result).

```
Like this => [
                 key: value *//does not have an index*
             ]

Accessed like this => this.list = result['someList'];
```

For example,

```
constructor(private httpClient: HttpCLient) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.getAll().subscribe(result => {
        this.someListInsideResult = result['someList'];
        console.log('result: ', result);
        console.log('someListInsideResult: ', someListInsideResult);
    }
}

getAll() {
    this.headers = new HttpHeaders().set('X-Authorization', 'Bearer  ' + token).set('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest').set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return httpClient.get(url, {headers: headers});
}
```

console:

```
// actual respose(result)
result: [
            key1: value1
            key2: value2
            ...
            ...
            someList: 0: "stringValue"
                      1: "ENUM"
                      2: null
        ]

// list inside the response
someListInsideResult: 0: "stringValue"
                      1: "ENUM"
                      2: null
```

if anyone can help that will very grateful.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the http call to a service, Lets say `UserService`:

**UserService.service.ts**

```
export class UserService{

getAll(): Observable<any> {
   this.headers = new HttpHeaders().set('X-Authorization', 'Bearer  ' + token).set('X- 
      Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest').set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
   return httpClient.get(url, {headers: headers});
}
}
```

In Controller, inject the service and use as

**User.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.userSvc.getAll().subscribe(result => {
        this.someListInsideResult = result['someList'];
        console.log('result: ', result);
        console.log('someListInsideResult: ', someListInsideResult);
    }
}
```

Then for testing create a mock service:

**MockUserService.ts**

```
export class MockUserService {

   getAll() {
    return of({
        key1: 'key1',
        someList : [{ "0" : "stringValue"}]
    })
   }

}
```

then in **User.component.spec.ts**

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [],
        declarations: [UserComponent],
        providers: [
          { provide: UserService, useClass: MockUserService }] // <-- Here we have injected our Mock
    }).compileComponents();
}));
```

Comment: Hi, @Shashank Vivek Thanks for fast reply, I tried your solution but was unable to set `key1: 'key1'` inside of of([]), as arrays does not take key,value pairs.

Comment: @SaurabhGupta , try `return of({` as updated. It was a typo :D

Comment: didn't make any difference, as it is now returning a json object. What I want is that it returns a list containing key,value pairs without having any indices. eg. `[ 'key': 'value' ]`

Comment: @SaurabhGupta `[ 'key': 'value' ]` makes difference. Its an array, if you want to insert, create an object and then insert something like `[ {'key': 'value' }]`

Comment: Did u try with updated `MockUserService.ts` as i mentioned in above comments ?

Comment: yes but it returns a ScalerObservable with key1 and someList inside value.

Comment: `ScalarObservable {_isScalar: true, value: Array(1), scheduler: null}
scheduler: null
value: Array(1)
0:
key: "value"
someList: Array(2)
0: {key1: "stringValue"}
1: {key2: "anotherOne"}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
_isScalar: true
__proto__: Observable`

Comment: what i want is like this `[ //(1)
no index here still not a JSON object with { }. key1: value1 heroList: [ //(2) array values with index ]` (1): accessed as res['key1'], (2) normal array with indices

Comment: @SaurabhGupta : dude, share the screenshot of `expected actual` response. You can tweak my `of({})` to achieve whatever you expect. From my answer you can get the idea of how to write it. Your comments are not clear to me

Comment: i am sorry for confusing you, it made the difference. saved my life. Thank you so so much.

Comment: @SaurabhGupta (^_^) . Cheers mate!